# How to filter select options based on logged in user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am working on an application that will be used by multiple users who belong to multiple companies.

The application will be used to log tickets, so support users must only see their own tickets. ( That is working fine)

```
        if (Auth::user()->role_id == 6) {
            return DataTables::of(Fault::where('assigned_to', Auth::user()->id))
                ->editColumn('company_id', function (Fault $fault) {
                    return $fault->company->name;
                })
                ->editColumn('service_id', function (Fault $fault) {
                    return $fault->service->name;
                })

                ->editColumn('city_id', function (Fault $fault) {
                    return $fault->city->name;
                })


                ->editColumn('assigned_to', function (Fault $fault) {
                    return $fault->user['name'];
                })

                ->editColumn('created_at', function (Fault $fault) {
                    return $fault->created_at->diffForHumans();
                })

                ->rawColumns(['action', 'fault_status_id', 'fault_priority_id'])

                ->addColumn('action',  function (Fault $fault) {
                    return '<a href="faults/' . $fault->id . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary ">Edit</a>';
                })

                ->toJson();
        }
```

My problem is now to only show the support user's company name on the companies drop down when they view the ticket details and not show all the other companies.

**I need this drop down to give me the logged in user's company and not list every company**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('company_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Company Name:</label>
    @if(Auth::user()->company_id = $fault->company_id)
    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="company_id" id='company_id' required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>=== Select Company ===
        </option>
        @foreach($companies as $entityId => $entityValue)
        <option value="{{ $entityId }}"
            {{ $fault->company_id === $entityId ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $entityValue }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @endif
    @if ($errors->has('company_id'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('company_id') }}</strong>
    </span>
@lse
    <option value="" selected disabled>=== Select Company ===
        </option>
        @foreach($companies as $entityId => $entityValue)
        <option value="{{ $entityId }}"
            {{ $fault->company_id === $entityId ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $entityValue }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: you should post your code .

Comment: @NipunTharuksha code added